# Create large diagonal sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I have a scaling parameter `x` and some matrix `A`. What I need to create is a `sparse` matrix such that

`A` is a square matrix:

```
A_00, A_01, A_02, A_03
A_10, A_11, A_12, A_13
A_20, A_21, A_22, A_23
A_30, A_31, A_32, A_33
```

and `x` is some integer. Then I want "create `x` many `0s` between element in `A`, and remove the diagonal matrix. That is, for `x=3` and `A` as above, my desired result would be:

```
0, 0, 0, A_01, 0, 0, A_02, 0, 0, A_03, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, A_01, 0, 0, A_02, 0, 0, A_03, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_01, 0, 0, A_02, 0, 0, A_03,
A_10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_12, 0, 0, A_13, 0, 0,
0, A_10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_12, 0, 0, A_13, 0,
0, 0, A_10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_12, 0, 0, A_13, 
A_20, 0, 0, A_21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_23, 0, 0,
0, A_20, 0, 0, A_21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_23, 0, 
0, 0, A_20, 0, 0, 0, A_21, 0, 0, 0, 0, A_23,
A_30, 0, 0, A_31, 0, 0, A_32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, A_30, 0, 0, A_31, 0, 0, A_32, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, A_30, 0, 0, A_31, 0, 0, A_32, 0, 0, 0,
```

I need this as a sparse matrix. For now, I am trying to create the diagonal elements using `kronecker` or `np.repeat` and then create the matrix using `scipy.sparse.diags`.

But perhaps there is a more efficient and/or cleaner way? Here, transparency beats (to a point) efficiency, if it makes the algorithm more readable. This is partially a mathematics question, but perhaps my desired output is the result of some `kronecker` product?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is better than your solution, but it seems pretty straightforward:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]], dtype='int')

def sparsify(A, expandFactor):
    newShape = map(lambda d:expandFactor*d, A.shape)
    B = np.zeros(newShape, dtype='int')
    # Repeatedly assign A to B skipping over expandFactor indices, with a different offset each time.
    for offset in range(expandFactor):
        B[offset::expandFactor,offset::expandFactor] = A       
    # Set diagonal of matrix to zero:
    B[range(newShape[0]), range(newShape[1])] = 0
    return B
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>> sparsify(A, 3)
array([[0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
       [7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that indeed, I could *almost* write output as

`np.kron(A, np.identity(x))`

So, here's what I'm doing now (if there's still something more efficient/cleaner, looking forward to it):

```
>>> A = np.arange(1, 10).reshape((3,3))
#`fill_diagonal` overwrites with reference. Create some `B` matrix to not mess with `A`:
>>> B = A.copy()
>>> np.fill_diagonal(B, 0)
>>> sparseA = sparse.csc_matrix(B)
>>> sparseA.toarray()
array([[0, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [7, 8, 0]])
>>> x = 3
>>> sparseE = sparse.identity(x)
>>> result = sparse.kron(sparseA, sparseE)
>>> result.todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  0.,  0.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  7.,  0.,  0.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  7.,  0.,  0.,  8.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Good use of `sparse.kron`.  `sparse` also has good tools for creating matrices directly from multiple diagonals.